# open window in same tab as parent, with variables from parent

Tags: javascript, tabs, window, parent-child, window.open

I currently have a button which opens a new window in a new tab using `window.open("newpage.html")`...I use `childVar = window.opener.parentGlobalVar` in the child window to retrieve the values of some global variables from the parent window.  Now I have been asked to open the new window in the same tab as the parent, and include a 'back' button to go back to the parent window.

So far, my attempts to do this have not worked, I've tried using **_top** or **_self** as arguments for `window.open`, `window.location`, and `location.href`... all of which fail to retrieve the needed variables from the parent; I assume these values are cleared when I open a new page in the same tab.   Is there a way that I can store these values (client-side) or pass them to the new window, if it opens in the same tab?

Comment: new window in the same tab ? urm

Comment: how is that a useful comment? granted I should have said 'new html page' instead of 'new window'...but this isn't noted in this unhelpful comment.

Comment: I guess you really have no idea as to why a comment is upvoted! It's also upvoted when the person who is upvoting it also has the same thought in mind. Makes Sense ?

Comment: is that why? b/c when I hover over the upvote arrow next to a comment, the popup text says 'this comment adds something useful to the post'. does you see something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use localStorage to store data client-side.

```
localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
var x = localStorage.getItem("bar");
```

Works kind of like cookies but there are also risks involved. I'd advice you to research it a little, starting for example [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

You can basically store everything in it, for example your referring URL.

**EDIT @comment:**

to clear the whole storage you can use:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

and to clear a certain key/value pair: `localStorage.removeItem(key)`
in terms of compatibility:
[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) is pretty decent.

Comment: this seems to work for me so far (testing in IE9, Chrome 31, FF 26) ... but I will need to check on some older browsers, and also how to clear only the items stored from my URL and not others....thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.

Once your `window` (page) has been unloaded (when the tab navigates to the new page), it no longer exists.

Instead, you can pass the data in the querystring.

Comment: Fragment identifier might be preferable to query string since it won't get sent to server

Comment: I appreciate the thoughts, but is 'you can't do that' really true, if the localStorage answer below works? (as it seems to, for me, so far)

Comment: @JasonBK: I mean you can't access the variable and execution context directly.  You can save them elsewhere, whether in the querystring, fragment, cookie, or local storage.

Comment: yes, but I did ask "Is there a way that I can store these values (client-side) or pass them to the new window, if it opens in the same tab?"...but I appreciate your response, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could try the `window.close("newpage.html")` method.. this would close the "newpage.html"(back button) and return to the original page (then they would just click the link they used to open the "newpage.html" if the need to view the page or return to the tab is necessary..

Code would be similar to:

```
<p>Click to close and return to last page.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">close</button>

<script>

function myFunction()
{
window.close("newpage.html");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am not seeing how this would help to pass data from the parent to the child html page?